# Windows 7 -> Ubuntu 16.04 via VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, mouse, guest-additions

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 via VirtualBox, it seems okay at first, but here comes the problem: there is two way mouse can interact in VirtualBox, integrated mouse and there's the other way, but it doesn't matter, they both do not work properly.
First method: mouse is not captured and can break from VirtualBox window. Problem: it seems like actual mouse position is not where I can see it, therefore when I'm trying to scroll, mouse position make window I want to scroll not in a scroll focus or something and it's not scrolling. There is literally no words to describe how frustrating this is.
And there is a second method:
Mouse is locked in VirtualBox window and cannot escape it. It seems okay, but here's the thing mouse update rate is like 5 fps or even less.

Okay, at this point I'm starting to think, maybe this "guest addition" may help me, I'm installing it and what do you think would happen? Glitches, a lot of them:
1. When I'm selecting something at desktop there is a trash from selection left and it can be cleared only by other selection.
2. Any popup menu can have more than one highlited selected option if I move mouse fast enough. It also can be fixed if I just force it to update by moving mouse again at that spot.
And yes, I saved the best for last.
3. Mouse cursor is invisible and cannot start being visible by any means.

And now the final question, what comes after "sudo" that can possible help me?

Comment: Did you, after installing the guest additions, reboot the virtual machine?

Comment: Yes, of course. I'm dealing with this around 5 days now. I even did install new virtual Ubuntu from scratch using same .iso file. It's all comes down to this scenario.

Comment: Try to update the **host** (Windows) graphics driver - it appears to be an issue with grapahics. Also, updating Virtualbox to most recent version (5.1.18 at present) may help. In any case it is a bug, not how it is supposed to be.

Comment: VirtualBox was 5.1.17 two days ago, yesterday I updated to 5.1.18 - nothing's changed. Just now I updated NVIDIA driver to 378.92 (this is the newest driver that NVIDIA has to offer) and yet still nothing has changed

Comment: Yes and about this "scroll focus" thing. I realized just now that real problem that affects at least gedit and QT Creator, is this: mouse can either move OR use wheel. This mean that if I'm scrolling down document and I do even 1px move with mouse it will freeze scrolling for about ~250 ms. This happen only when mouse is integrated (VirtualBox) or not optimazed for games (VMware)

Comment: This may seem silly but how much video memory did you allocate to the virtual machine and did you enable 3D acceleration under the virtual machine settings?

Comment: I allocated 128MB, that's the maximum as far as I can tell and yes, I did enable 3D acceleration, but... it seems hopeless, all this bugs, something not working and I ending up blaming virtual machine. I got tired of this and I did setup second PC